# Are $i,j,k$ commutative?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

I am trying to understand quaternions. I read that Hamilton came up with the great equation:

A) $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = −1$

In this equation I understand that $i,j,k$ are complex numbers.

Later on, I read that

B) $ij=k$

C) $ji=-k$

So, if $i,j,k$ are complex numbers, and complex number multiplication is commutative, why are these two equations different? I do understand that quaternion multiplication is non-commutative, but I do not understand why multiplying these complex components are also non-commutative.

Could someone please help me understand what is going on here. I (obviously) am not an expert in mathematics, so a simple explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $i,j,$ and $k$ are not complex numbers in this context.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. I think I meant to say imaginary. Are imaginary number multiplication commutative?!

Comment: That isn't an equation

Comment: ${\bf i}, {\bf j}, {\bf k}$ are not complex number and they don't commute with each other. However, subsets of quaternions of the form $\{ a + b {\bf i} : (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$, $\{ a + b {\bf j} : (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}, \ldots$ are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ in terms of its algebraic properties. Sometimes we will treat $\mathbb{C}$ as if it is a subset of the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ by identifying $i \in \mathbb{C}$ with ${\bf i}$ or ${\bf j}$ or other pure imaginary unit quaternions.

Answer (score 2):

We can *extend* the complex numbers ($a+bi,\ a,b\in\Bbb R$) with *further* two imaginary units, named $j$ and $k$, and *if we pose* those equations, we arrive to the quaternions, where commutativity indeed fails by B) and C).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I believe I had complex and imaginary confused.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed commutativity still holds in the quaternions if your complex number only contains i's, j's or k's. I.e. any number's of the form $a + bi + 0j + 0k$ are commutative to each other, similarly $a + 0i + bj + 0k$ is commutative with other numbers of that form also and same with $a + 0i + 0j + bk$. However commutativity doesn't hold over the entire group of quaternions equipped with multiplication as its operation. $\mathbb{Q}_8$ is a non-abelian group in other words.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $z,z'$ are quaternions. We may write these as $z = a + w$, $z' = a' + w'$ where $a,a'$ are real and $w, w'$ are "purely quarternion" in the sense that if we write out $w$ it is simply some linear combination of $i,j,k$ with no real component. If we identify $i,j,k$ with standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ thus thinking of $w,w'$ as vectors then we have $ww' = -(w \cdot w') + w \times w'$ (where again the first term is the real component, the second term is quaternion one).

$$z z' = (aa' - w \cdot w') + (aw' + a'w + w \times w')$$
$$z' z = (aa' - w \cdot w') + (aw' + a'w + w' \times w)$$
$$ zz' - z'z = w \times w' - w' \times w = 2(w \times w')$$

So commutativity fails precisely when the imaginary quaternion parts aren't colinear.